# Prepared Statement Joins in Java

Tags: java, oracle, join, jdbc, plsql

Is it possible to do Joins in java using prepared statements?

```
public class Test {

    static Connection conn;
    static PreparedStatement ps;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

        String sql = "select addr.address_id from address addr inner join pizza_stores ps on addr.address_id = ps.address_id";

        conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println("DEBUG--: before query");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);



        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("addr.address_id"));
        }

        ps.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   


    }

}
```

I get no results but when I run in sql developer I do get results (ex ADDRESS_ID -> 1, 2 ,3). I will be using stored procedure for this later. I am just curious.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the sql statement.  There is something else going on here that is not obvious.

Comment: There seems to be an error with how you used "prepareStatement". You first called ` ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);` and then passing in the sql again `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);`. However, I think it should work as you do not have any inputs to set. The blank resultset could be down to the db user connected? Try using rs.getIn(1) instead of column name?

Comment: Try using `getInt("address_id")` instead of `getInt("addr.address_id")`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

So I had two tables (address and pizza_stores).

When I created the pizza_stores table, in the FK, I referenced it to the pizza_stores table (same table) instead of address table. Therefore it wasn't printing anything.

The java code works it was more of a constraint problem in sql.